# PHP Notifications Event

Tags: php, notifications, forum, email-notifications

How would one achieve PHP email notifications? I have created a forum, and was wondering how I would create a notification system/event that fires when a topic is replied to?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Somewhere in your function to save a reply you'd add a check for people subscribed to the thread and email them?

Comment: Eh, I didn't think about that. I'll give it a try

Comment: "IF" by chance that you're using Wordpress (which I know isn't tagged as so), believe they have a plug-in or plug-ins for something especially made for such a task.

Comment: You can have a table of comments, with the id of the owner-creator and a table of replyes with the id of the comment...every time someone reply that post, check for the owner and email him with the content of the reply...something like that

Comment: And if not (Wordpress), then you could also make use of a [`trigger`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) in MySQL along with what `(Digital) Chris` mentioned.